# bootstrap modal not triggering the event

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSample" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Sample" OnClick="btnSample_Click" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divHideShow" />
```

this code is not triggering the Onclick event of the button.
I want to show the div and triggering the onclick event.